# query with several LEFT JOIN , not getting desired result

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Here's a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0576f/4)

Can anyone tell me how can I get this output using `LEFT JOIN`?

```
 notification_recipient  pm_sender    msg     modification_page_id 
 Peter                   Tom          Hello   NULL
 notification_recipient  pm_sender    msg     modification_page_id 
 Peter                   NULL         NULL    2
```

Here's the query that I have tried:

```
   SELECT u.name AS notification_recipient,us.name AS pm_sender,
          p.msg,um.page_id AS modification_page_id 
    FROM notification n 
    LEFT JOIN pm p ON p.pm_id = n.pm_id
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = p.recipent_id
    LEFT JOIN users us ON us.user_id = p.sender_id
    LEFT JOIN user_modification um ON um.modification_id = n.modification_id
    WHERE u.name = 'Peter'
    AND n.is_read = '0'
```

I was looking for some sort conditional join, which means joining different tables based on whether a value exists in a field, but I couldn't find one that would work on my example. Any other efficient solution would also be appreciated.

Background:

I'm planning to make a notification system that sends out different types of messages to users (private messages among users, message that their modifications to an entry has been approved etc).
When a user logs in, I want to make a query to find out if there's any unread notifications for that user. If yes, a notification will be sent to him via Ajax.

To illustrate, suppose that Tom has sent a private message to Peter and his modification to an entry is approved, two triggers from table `pm` and `user_modification` will be invoked to add two new rows into `notification`. Column `pm_id` is referenced by `pm` and `modification_id` is by `modification`. `is_read` is defaulted `0` as Not Read.

Here's the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE notification
    (`id` int, `modification_id` int,`pm_id` int,`is_read` int)
;

INSERT INTO notification
    (`id`,`modification_id`,`pm_id`,`is_read`)
VALUES
    (1,1,NULL,0),
    (2,NULL,1,0),
    (3,2,NULL,0)
;

CREATE TABLE user_modification
    (`modification_id` int, `user_id` int,`page_id` int, `is_approved` int)
;

INSERT INTO user_modification
    (`modification_id`,`user_id`,`page_id`,`is_approved`)
VALUES
    (1,1,5,1),
    (2,2,2,1),
    (3,3,3,0)

;

CREATE TABLE pm
    (`pm_id` int, `sender_id` int,`recipent_id` int,`msg` varchar(200))
;

INSERT INTO pm
    (`pm_id`,`sender_id`,`recipent_id`,`msg`)
VALUES
    (1,1,2,'Hello');

CREATE TABLE users
    (`user_id` int, `name`varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`user_id`,`name`)
VALUES
    (1,'Tom'),
    (2,'Peter'),
    (3,'David')
;
```

Here's the output I want for a notification if user David logs in. Each row for each message type.

```
 notification_recipient  pm_sender    msg     modification_page_id 
 Peter                   Tom          Hello   NULL
 notification_recipient  pm_sender    msg     modification_page_id 
 Peter                   NULL         NULL    2
```

The notification to Peter will be like this:

```
        `1.You have received a private message from Tom.
         2.your modification on <a href='mysite.com/5'>that page</a> is approved`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do the job. Here's [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0576f/33/0)

```
SELECT
  n.id,
  IF(pmu.name IS NULL, pmm.name, pmu.name) recipient, 
  pmus.name sender, pm.msg, m.modification_id
FROM
  notification n
  LEFT JOIN user_modification m ON (n.modification_id = m.modification_id)
  LEFT JOIN pm ON (n.pm_id = pm.pm_id)
  LEFT JOIN users pmu ON (pm.recipent_id = pmu.user_id)
  LEFT JOIN users pmus ON (pm.sender_id = pmus.user_id)
  LEFT JOIN users pmm ON (m.user_id = pmm.user_id)
WHERE
  (pmu.name = 'Peter' OR 
     pmm.name = 'Peter') AND
  n.is_read = 0;
```